# How to search using variable to match any string - shell

Tags: shell, unix

How to search part of the string using variable and assign to new variables

My Search variable is : `db_uni_name=testdb_iac3bd`

My Oratab File is:

```
+ASM1:/u01/app/12.2.0.1/grid:N
oidiaddb:/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_2:Y
testdb:/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_3:Y
oradb:/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_4:Y
```

I want to search `$db_uni_name` to find matching db name and path

In this case, i want to search for testdb and assign as follows:

```
DB_NAME=testdb
ORACLE_HOME=/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/Documents$ DB_NAME=$(echo $db_uni_name | grep `awk -F'_' '{print $1}'` Oratab.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
mayankp@mayank:~/Documents$ echo $DB_NAME
testdb
mayankp@mayank:~/Documents$ ORACLE_HOME=$(echo $db_uni_name | grep `awk -F'_' '{print $1}'` Oratab.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
mayankp@mayank:~/Documents$ echo $ORACLE_HOME 
/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_3
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here another way to print out the values.

```
$ awk -F: -v patt=${db_uni_name%_*} \
 '$0~patt{print "DB_NAME="$1; print "ORACLE_HOME="$2}' inputFile
DB_NAME=testdb
ORACLE_HOME=/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_3
```

It uses `%_*` to separate `testdb` from `_iac3d`. Then use `awk` to search and print.

If you want to `export` those variables in the current shell, then use the following, which adds `export` to the print and then evaluates using `$()`

```
$ $(awk -F: -v patt=${db_uni_name%_*} '$0~patt{print "export DB_NAME="$1; print "export ORACLE_HOME="$2}' inputFile)
$ echo $DB_NAME
testdb
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_3
```