# find matching name in a file using variable 1 and replace using variable 2 shell

Tags: shell, unix

My oratab file has following content:

```
cat /etc/oratab
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#
+ASM1:/u01/app/12.2.0.1/grid:N
exaiaddb:/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_2:Y
nttest:/u02/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_3:Y
```

Variable 1 : `$DB_NAME=nttest`

Variable 2:  `$DB_UNI_NAME=nttest_iad92`

I simply want to find `$DB_NAME` in above file and replace with `$DB_UNI_NAME`

I tried the following, but it is not updating the file

`sed -i 's/${DB_NAME}/${db_uni_name}/g' oratab`

Comment: Please explain why the answers you received to [yesterdays Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992875/how-to-search-using-variable-to-match-any-string-shell) aren't helping you . Please update your Q above to include your best attempt at solving your problem, or we'll just think you can't be bothered. Good luck.

Comment: This is replace and update the file for permanent change. I am not sure about replacing/updating the file with new variable, so i raised this question

Comment: " Please update your Q above to include your best attempt at solving your problem" ...  This sort of Q gets asked every week here. try searching for `[bash] [sed] use shell variables`. Good luck.

Comment: `sed -i 's/${DB_NAME}/${db_uni_name}/g' oratab` ... Change the *single-quotes* to *double-quote* to allow *variable-expansion* to take place.... *Single-quotes* ***prevent*** *variable-expansion*, so your `sed` command is literally looking for the characters `${DB_NAME}` (that is `'$'`, `'{'`, `'D'`, `'B'`, ....) in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are using has 2 mistakes:

1.) You used the variable `${db_uni_name}` in `sed` command. Instead, you should have used `DB_UNI_NAME` as you declared this above. (see difference in the case)

2.) Use double-quotes`(" ")` instead of single-quotes `(' ')` in `sed` command.
`"` makes sure that `sed` expands the variables.

So, your command would be:

```
sed -i "s/${DB_NAME}/${DB_UNI_NAME}/g" oratab
```

This should work. Let me know.